# Discord bot issue "is a required argument missing" python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a problem. I think this code is well written and the bot turns on and everything, but when I go to execute the commad `play`  I get an error.

```
@bot.command(name='play', aliases=['sing','p'], description="streams music")
async def play_(ctx, self, *, search: str):
    #async def play_(ctx, message, self, *, search: str):
    """Request a song and add it to the queue.
    This command attempts to join a valid voice channel if the bot is not already in one.
    Uses YTDL to automatically search and retrieve a song.
    Parameters
    ------------
    search: str [Required]
        The song to search and retrieve using YTDL. This could be a simple search, an ID or URL.
    """
    await ctx.trigger_typing()

    vc = ctx.voice_client

    if not vc:
        await ctx.invoke(self.connect_)

    player = self.get_player(ctx)

    # If download is False, source will be a dict which will be used later to regather the stream.
    # If download is True, source will be a discord.FFmpegPCMAudio with a VolumeTransformer.
    source = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx, search, loop=self.bot.loop, download=False)

    await player.queue.put(source)
```

The error is as follows:

```
    discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: search is a required argument that is missing.
```

And I don't know what to do because I have already tried to change the position but an error keeps coming out if someone knows what it is, please tell me

Comment: Why are you passing `self` as an argument if the command is not in a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever your `search` parameter is for, it wont work.
When the discord.py library calls a command, it calls the command as follows:

```py
command(context, word1, word2, word3)
```

So if it would call your function, the named error would apper, because discord never passes a `search` argument to your function. E.g:

```py
@bot.command(name='play', aliases=['sing','p'], description="streams music")
async def play_(ctx, self, *, search: str):
    [...]
```

> -play see you again

```py
play_(context, "see", "you", "again")
```

-> `Error: search is a required argument that is missing`

---

Instead, your function should look like the following:

```py
@bot.command(name='play', aliases=['sing','p'], description="streams music")
async def play_(ctx, *search):
    [...]
```

Comment: @LeoCalpe As I said at the end, your function should take the parameters `(ctx, *search)`. The `*search` parameter will contain a tuple of all words that were passed (in my example `("see", "you", "again")`. I don't know if you need the `self` parameter, but it looks like your function is not part of a class, so you wouldnt need to specify `self`. If, unless, it is part of a class, put `self` at the beginning: `(self, ctx, *search)`.

Comment: If I do that it is fine but it gives me the following error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'trigger_typing'`

Comment: In this case, no `self` argument gets passed either, so try to just use `(ctx, *search)`

Comment: But it gives me this error: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: Yes, because self is, as it sais, not defined. You never specified it anywere. I suppose your code is copy-pasted from somewhere, and I would really recommend you to first learn a bit more python before trying to write complex programs such as a music bot. I can help you at your main question, but I dont know what you're exactly trying to do. Errors such as these are the basic concepts of programming, so I would suggest you to start with easier tasks. Dont be discouraged by all these errors, but try to learn the langauge step by step before going back to your original project.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, I have been learning for about a week and I have already tried things and they work well for me, I am getting the hang of it but I wanted my bot to play music, which I got but it was very crappy, so I decided to look for something better and I came across With this, and at first I saw it very well but when it has given me errors because some I have managed to remove with my knowledge but others have been impossible for me, I am here, in truth this is only a part of the code but it has much more,

Comment: I will listen to you and study more about it, thank you very much for everything;)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `self` as a parameter? If you're in a cog, put it before `ctx`. If you're not, remove that parameter. Your search term is being passed as the `self` parameter.

Comment: I have already done it and I keep getting the same error.